# How to iterate over an array of arrays to filter out or reject duplicate entries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, filter, splice

I want to iterate over this 2-dimensional array. Arrays with multiple objects have multiple entries in the same month (in the example below January). I want to filter out (reject) the duplicate entries and want to return the altered array.

I tried different solutions here on SO but failed so far; I will appreciate any input!

```
[[
  { "id":"9","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-01-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"10","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-01-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"9","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-01-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"10","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-01-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"29","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-01-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"30","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-01-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"29","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-01-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"30","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-01-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
]]
```

Edit answer to traktor:
I guess the minimum would be to check if every subarray is unique.
So if the filter finds for example the same id a second time, the whole duplicate array should get removed.

Edit answer to Peter Seliger:
The result should keep the 2-dimensional structure.

```
[
  [{
    "id": "1",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-09-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "2",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-08-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "3",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-07-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "4",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-06-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "5",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-05-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "6",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-04-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "7",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-03-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "12",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-03-24",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "8",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-02-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "11",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-02-23",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "9",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-01-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "10",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-01-23",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "9",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-01-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "10",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-01-23",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "8",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-02-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "11",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-02-23",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "7",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-03-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "12",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2021-03-24",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "21",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-09-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "22",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-08-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "23",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-07-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "24",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-06-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "25",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-05-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "26",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-04-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "27",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-03-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "32",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-03-24",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "200"
  }], [{
    "id": "28",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-02-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "31",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-02-23",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "400"
  }], [{
    "id": "29",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-01-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "30",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-01-23",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "29",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-01-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "30",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-01-23",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }], [{
    "id": "28",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-02-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "31",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-02-23",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "400"
  }], [{
    "id": "27",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-03-22",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "100"
  }, {
    "id": "32",
    "bookingReason": "Netto Neu Eigen",
    "bookingDate": "2022-03-24",
    "bookingType": "Gutschrift",
    "bookingPoints": "200"
  }]
]
```

Comment: What _minimum_ testing needs to be conducted to establish that two entries in the main array are duplicates?  You may also wish to clarify if the filtering algorithm needs to preform validity checks on what it allows through. (Please edit the question to add additional information rather than trying to add it as a comment).

Comment: @traktor Ok I did, hope that helps

Comment: @AlexJanow ... please provide the data structure as syntactically correct / valid object literal, reduced to the most necessary data (and not as incomplete/folded copy-and-paste-dump from the console). Right now one can only guess the correct structure of what the OP refers to as  _"array of arrays"_.

Comment: @AlexJanow ... Another important information is missing. Does the result need to keep the 2-dimensional array structure? Or should the target structure be a flat(tened) array of unique (in terms of the OP by unique `id` value) items?

Comment: @Peter Seliger, edited, I hope that is what you meant.

Comment: please add what you have and what you want. please use comments for the parts you don't want to include into the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the OP actually means with ...

> *"I want to filter out the double entries and want to return the filtered array."*

... is that the OP wants to mutate either the provided data structure directly or maybe a [structured clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) of it. This becomes more clear with ...

> *"So if the filter finds for example the same id a second time, the whole duplicate array should get removed."*

> > *"Edit answer to Peter Seliger: The result should keep the 2-dimensional structure."*

Thus one has to come up with a recursively working ***reject**ing* approach.

The provided implementation uses a lookup for a custom key (property name) specific value. In case the value does not yet exist, the iteration proceeds but the value gets assigned to the lookup. Any array item which features the same, already assigned, value gets [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)ed from the array (which is a mutation task) and pushed into the local `rejected` array. The function's return value is an object which features two arrays ... `mutated` with a reference to the passed and processed/mutated data structure and `rejected` which is a flat list of items that were rejected from the provided data structure.

```js
function rejecItemsOfSameKeyAndValueRecursively(
  arr = [], key = '', lookup = new Map,
) {
  const rejected = [];

  for (let idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx++) {
    const item = arr[idx];

    if (Array.isArray(item)) {

      // recursion in order to handle nested array structures.
      rejected
        .push(
          ...rejecItemsOfSameKeyAndValueRecursively(item, key, lookup).rejected
        );

      // ... and in case one wants to also get rid
      //     of the now possibly empty array item ...
      if (item.length === 0) {
        // remove empty array item.
        arr.splice(idx, 1);
        // re/adjust the proceeding index value.
        --idx; 
      }

    } else if (!!item && typeof item === 'object') {
      const value = item[key];

      if (lookup.has(value)) {

        rejected
          .push(
            // remove duplicate item from array.
            arr.splice(idx, 1)
          );

        --idx; // re/adjust the proceeding index value.

      } else {
        lookup.set(value, value);
      }
    }
  }
  return { mutated: arr, rejected };
}

const sampleData = [[
  { "id":"1","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-09-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"2","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-08-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"3","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-07-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"4","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-06-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"5","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-05-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"6","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-04-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"7","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-03-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"12","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-03-24","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"8","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-02-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"11","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-02-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"9","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-01-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"10","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-01-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"9","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-01-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"10","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-01-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"8","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-02-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"11","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-02-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"7","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-03-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"12","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2021-03-24","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"21","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-09-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"22","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-08-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"23","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-07-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"24","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-06-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"25","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-05-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"26","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-04-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"27","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-03-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"32","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-03-24","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"200" }
], [
  { "id":"28","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-02-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"31","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-02-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"400" }
], [
  { "id":"29","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-01-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"30","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-01-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"29","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-01-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"30","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-01-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" }
], [
  { "id":"28","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-02-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"31","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-02-23","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"400" }
], [
  { "id":"27","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-03-22","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"100" },
  { "id":"32","bookingReason":"Netto Neu Eigen","bookingDate":"2022-03-24","bookingType":"Gutschrift","bookingPoints":"200" }
]];

const cloneDataStructure = (typeof structuredClone === 'function')
  ? structuredClone
  : value => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));


const data = cloneDataStructure(sampleData);
const { mutated, rejected } = rejecItemsOfSameKeyAndValueRecursively(data, 'id');

console.log(
  '... mutated/rejected by `id` ... ',
);
console.log(
  '(mutated === data) ?..',
  (mutated === data),
);
console.log(
  { mutated, rejected },
);


const data_2 = cloneDataStructure(sampleData);
const { mutated: mutated_2, rejected: rejected_2 } =
  rejecItemsOfSameKeyAndValueRecursively(cloneDataStructure(data_2), 'bookingPoints');

console.log(
  '... mutated/rejected by `bookingPoints` ... ',
);
console.log(
  '(mutated_2 === data_2) ?..',
  (mutated_2 === data_2),
);
console.log(
  { mutated_2, rejected_2 },
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @AlexJanow ... you are welcome. And please notice the minor update which actually follows the wish of also discarding entirely empty array items (the once which got emptied by rejecting duplicate items).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm reading the question correctly, but if all you need to do is take this ragged 2-d array and filter out duplicate entries from any of those nested arrays, then I think it's pretty simple:

```js
const dedupe = (
  data, found = new Set(), result,
  test = (x) => ((result = ! found .has (x .id)), (found .add (x .id)), result)
) => data .map ((group) => group .filter (test)) .filter (x => x .length > 0)


const data = [[{id: "1", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-09-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "2", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-08-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "3", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-07-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "4", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-06-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "5", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-05-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "6", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-04-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "7", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-03-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "12", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-03-24", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "8", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-02-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "11", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-02-23", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "9", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-01-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "10", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-01-23", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "9", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-01-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "10", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-01-23", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "8", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-02-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "11", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-02-23", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "7", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-03-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "12", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2021-03-24", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "21", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-09-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "22", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-08-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "23", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-07-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "24", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-06-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "25", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-05-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "26", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-04-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "27", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-03-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "32", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-03-24", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "200"}], [{id: "28", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-02-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "31", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-02-23", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "400"}], [{id: "29", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-01-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "30", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-01-23", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "29", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-01-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "30", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-01-23", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}], [{id: "28", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-02-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "31", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-02-23", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "400"}], [{id: "27", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-03-22", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "100"}, {id: "32", bookingReason: "Netto Neu Eigen", bookingDate: "2022-03-24", bookingType: "Gutschrift", bookingPoints: "200"}]]

console .log (dedupe (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We write something I usually try to avoid: a stateful function closing over a mutable Set of the `id`s we've seen so far.  This function is used as the callback for `filter` calls on the nested arrays.  I tend to avoid stateful functions, but the alternative seemed to complex be nested folds, and this works well.

I made the assumption that we don't want empty groups left after removing any basic duplicates.  If that assumption is wrong, we can simply remove the final `filter` call.

That version is syntactically dense.  The following variant might be more appealing to some folks:

```js
const dedupe = (data) => {
  const found = new Set()
  const test = (x) => {
    const result = ! found .has (x .id)
    found .add (x .id)
    return result
  }
  return data .map ((group) => group .filter (test)) 
              .filter (x => x .length > 0)
}
```

They do the same thing.